# Word DocumentBeforeClose event not working sometimes

Tags: vba, ms-word, vb6

I am maintaining a Word related vb6 project. When we download a word document from our server and make changes on it. Then click Close.

Then 
the `objWord_DocumentBeforeClose` event will occur. 
If the downloaded file has not uploaded back to server, then we prompt a yes/no message box `Do you want to check-in the document?`

If clicked on 'Yes' and if click again on `ctrl+w` before the check-in process completed, document will close without reaching the `mobjWord_DocumentBeforeClose`event.

I have added some code in the DocumentBeforeClose event to prevent closing the document if the check-in process is running using document variables.

Could anybody please explain me why the `mobjWord_DocumentBeforeClose` is not reaching at the second close click?

Below is my code.

```
Private Sub mobjWord_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim objDoc As Project.Document
Dim objApp As Project.Application
Dim strProcess As String

Set objApp = New Project.Application
If objApp.Settings.RespondToWordEvents Then
    Set objDoc = objApp.GetDocument(Doc)
    'Check the document variable to seen if any process is running with the document
   If objDoc.IsBusy = False Then
        if objDoc.NotCheckedIn
             If objDoc.DownloadProperties.WasCheckedOut Then
                Select Case MsgBox("Do you want to check-in the document?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion)
                    Case vbYes
                        If objApp.CheckInDocument(WordDocument:=Doc) Is Nothing Then
                            Cancel = True
                        End If
                        fDisebleCheckIn = True
                    Case vbNo
                        fDisebleCheckIn = True
                    Case vbCancel
                        Cancel = True
                End Select
            End If
        Else
            //some code
        End If
    Else
        Cancel = True
        strProcess = ProcessInProgress(objDoc, objApp)
        MsgBox objApp.GetUIString("Unable to close the document " + strProcess + "process is running"), vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    End If
End If

ErrorHandler:
    objApp.Quit
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your additional code in VB6? or the documents VBA?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, My project includes a vb6 code (ActiveX dll) and a .dotm file (our ribbon bar).

Comment: I am not sure how this code is set up, so the code is in the VB6 project relating to the `mobjWord` object, also created in VB6?  I think you'll need to create a class with automated events from a base of `word.application`

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] meaning code that will run that lets us reproduce what you're doing. We can't even tell if the code you show us is in the VB6 project or the VBA project! Also, what object is `Project`? We can't know what `Project.Document` and `Project-Applciation` are. And so on...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand you, but in VBA, so you can adapt for your VB6, I would have the following in a normal module

```
Public wdCustomWordApplication As clsCustomWordApplication

Sub Setup()

Dim w As Word.Application

Set w = New Word.Application
w.Visible = True

Set wdCustomWordApplication = New clsCustomWordApplication
wdCustomWordApplication.InitialiseCustomWordApplication w

End Sub
```

and then a class module called clsCustomWordApplication, like so

```
Private WithEvents wdWordApplication As Word.Application

Public Sub InitialiseCustomWordApplication(objWord As Word.Application)
    Set wdWordApplication = objWord
End Sub

Private Sub wdWordApplication_DocumentBeforeClose( _
    ByVal Doc As Word.Document, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Some question"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.